# Are there any tools with a GUI to manage Selenium Webdriver test runs and results?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Are there any tools with a GUI that allow managing Selenium Webdriver test execution and displaying pass/fail results on screen?

If not, are there any full test management tools like QC than can be integrated with Selenium to start tests and store results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), which is a open source tool.

That would allow you to:

- run different tests with different jobs
- run the tests with headless browsers
- integrate TestNG/Custom reports to track the results in HTML format.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into Jenkins, I didn't know it could be used for running Selenium tests.